# Why Wife reacted differently to his husband words?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Husband reading the newspaper & said this words :

> Just let the faceless marauding corporate monsters of America destroy
>   everything beautiful about this town.

For this statement, his wife reacted differently by saying this words:

> Corporate monsters or not, Epic Mart's **a lot cheaper**.

here Husband didn't say anything about cheaper or costlier in his statement, then why his wife mentioned **cheaper** in her sentence?

Comment: It's a joke, based on a rather objectionable sexual stereotype. The stereotype is that men are concerned with important things like politics and local heritage, and that women are too stupid to care about those and only care about what store is cheapest. (You see why I say it is objectionable?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a clip online [here](http://video.anyclip.com/movies/halloween-2007/halloween-breakfast/#!quotes/). Earlier, the dad mentioned that a local  hardware store, "Nickle's Hardware",  was going out of business. This seems to be a [mom-and-pop shop](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mom-and-pop-store) (small business), since it had been there for forty-two years and they know Mr. Nickle.  When the father makes the remark given in the OP, he's upset that the large corporations are crushing small businesses, and presumably destroying other features of the town.

As @StoneyB points out, "Epic Mart" is supposed to be representative of large corporations that drive local stores out of business. The name Epic Mart is a reference to [Wal-Mart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walmart), a corporation notorious for hurting local businesses with their extremely low prices. The wife makes that remark to show her indifference.  She doesn't care whether the corporations are hurting local businesses or not. She likes the low prices.

Comment: Excellent point, thanks. I tried to incorporate it in my answer.